# AVR Not Resetting Properly

Tags: avr

I am facing an issue where my AVR is not resetting properly upon power up.This is the first time I am facing such issue.

I have a Nokia LCD connected to AVR and upon startup (and after some delay and after initializing the LCD display), the AVR is supposed to toggle an LED and then display a test pattern on the LCD.

Sometimes when I power up the system, the LED gets toggled but nothing is displayed on the LCD. But when I connect a naked wire to the AVR reset pin and touch it, the system resets (the LED toggles again) and this time the test pattern is displayed correctly.

I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: The reset when you touch that naked wire could be ESD related and not something you should carry on doing - unless you want to potentially kill your micro. As for the LCD not initialising reliably, I'd guess that you have a border-line timing issue somewhere in your init procedure.

Comment: That was it! I checked my init code and I had missed a delay. Problem solve! Thanks for the ESD bit, hadnt thought about that. If you could add this as a reply, I would accept this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset when you touch that naked wire could be ESD related and not something you should carry on doing - unless you want to potentially kill your micro.

As for the LCD not initialising reliably, I'd guess that you have a border-line timing issue somewhere in your init procedure.